# PHP Faster associative array sort

Tags: php, sorting, optimization, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I would like to know if there is a way/method I could sort these kind of array faster (even if its 0.05 faster). Array are generally 700 kb size

```
$price_posi = array();

$i = 0;
foreach ($results["items"] as $one_item)
{
    if($a == 1)
    {
        $price_posi[i] =  $one_item["price"]["paxgroup"][0]["cost"] + $one_item["price"]["paxgroup"][0]["othertotal"];
    }
    else if($b == 1)
    {
        $price_posi[i] =  $one_item["price"]["paxgroup"][0]["cost"];
    }
    else if($c == 1)
    {
        $price_posi[i] =  $one_item["price"]["paxgroup"][0]["wholesale"] + $one_item["price"]["paxgroup"][0]["othertotal"];
    }
    else if($d == 1)
    {
        $price_posi[i] =  $one_item["price"]["paxgroup"][0]["wholesale"];
    }

    // Other actions on $results ....

    $i++;
}

asort ($price_posi);

$sorted_results = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($price_posi as $key => $price)
{
    $sorted_results["items"][$i] = $results["items"][$key];
    $i++;
}

$sorted_results["segments"] = $results["segments"];

$results = $sorted_results;
```

I know asort is already really fast but I have to loop through my array 2 times to be able to use asort since my array is a multidimensional associative array.

Comment: Give us some sample data

Comment: Why do you need to loop through twice? And if the data is coming from a database, why not let that order your data?

Comment: @MarkBaker the data is not comming from a database, we receive xml from an API that we convert into json

Comment: Well consider using `uasort()` directly against `$results`, and then I don't see any need to iterate over the array at all

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bad idea to have compared in each iteration.

You should put different foreach into different if/elseif statements.

Also you can use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) function.